# Number list with no repeats and ordered

Tags: python

This code returns a list [0,0,0] to [9,9,9], which produces no repeats and each element is in order from smallest to largest.

```
def number_list():
    b=[]
    for position1 in range(10):
        for position2 in range(10):
            for position3 in range(10):
                if position1<=position2 and position2<=position3:
                    b.append([position1, position2, position3])

    return b
```

Looking for a shorter and better way to write this code without using multiple variables (position1, position2, position3), instead only using one variable `i`.

Here is my attempt at modifying the code, but I'm stuck at implementing the `if` statements:

```
def number_list():
    b=[]
    for i in range(1000):
        b.append(map(int, str(i).zfill(3)))
    return b
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you **could** write `if pos1<=position2<=position3:` - this is valid python. Doesn't help, but good to know.

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a recursive algorithm

Comment: Here's a not-serious one: `list(set(map(tuple, map(sorted, product(range(10), repeat=3)))))`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the same note as the other [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) answer, there is another way with [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(10), 3))
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply use list comprehension, one way to do it:

```
 >>> [[x,y,z] for x in range(10) for y in range(10) for z in range(10) if x<=y and y<=z]
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 6], 
[0, 0, 7], [0, 0, 8], [0, 0, 9], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 5], [0, 1, 6], [0, 1, 7], [0, 1, 8], [0, 1, 9], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], 
[0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 5], [0, 2, 6], [0, 2, 7], [0, 2, 8], [0, 2, 9], [0, 3, 3], 
[0, 3, 4], [0, 3, 5], [0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 7], [0, 3, 8],....[6, 8, 8], [6, 8, 9], 
[6, 9, 9], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 8], [7, 7, 9], [7, 8, 8], [7, 8, 9], [7, 9, 9], 
[8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 9], [8, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9]]
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish OP's goal. OP expressed an invariant that each element is in order from smallest to largest.

Comment: You need to add the if condition

Comment: @dursk, I still don't get it, aren't they from smallest to largest?

Comment: `[0, 1, 0]`, for instance, is illegal in OP's condition.

Comment: Updated, Thanks for the head's up

Comment: I think this is the best answer as it uses only vanilla python - no modules.

Comment: itertools is "vanilla python" just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simpler way than doing the checks, but which is still IMO worse than `combinations_with_replacement`:

```
[(a, b, c) for a in range(10)
           for b in range(a, 10)
           for c in range(b, 10)]
```

Namely, instead of filtering values after production you just only produce those values you want in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to eliminate nested loops:

```
>>> filter(lambda i: i[0] <= i[1] <= i[2],
...     itertools.product(range(10), range(10), range(10)))
```

Or better with list comprehensions:

```
>>> numbers = itertools.product(range(10), range(10), range(10))
>>> [(a, b, c) for a, b, c in numbers if a <= b <= c]
```

Comment: Almost there but the checks should be `<=` instead of `<`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worthwhile to point out that the original code is weird and can be rewritten easily to be simpler:

```
def number_list2():
    b=[]
    for position1 in range(10):
        for position2 in range(position1, 10):
            for position3 in range(position2, 10):
                if position1<=position2 and position2<=position3:
                    b.append([position1, position2, position3])

    return b
```

There are better solutions here, but this one is the stepping stone to getting to them.

Answer (score 0):

This code could be done pretty easily with recursion, without using `itertools`.

1. `n` - being the length of the tuple
2. `m` - being the upper bound of each value

The Code:

```
def non_decreasing(n, m):
  if n==0:
    return []
  if n==1:
    return [[i] for i in range(1,m+1)]
  return [[i] + t for t in non_decreasing(n-1, m) for i in range(1,t[0]+1)]
```

The result is the output of `non_decreasing(3,9)`